# appending given number of values to a list every second in real time

Tags: python

I need a list of binary data, where, the number of bits in the list needs to be growing based on a certain rate, for example 1000 bits per second in real time. I am not asking to execute my code after every second, instead, the specified number of bits should be added to the list within one second and same number of bits should be added during the next second in real time, and so on, until I explicitly stop this process. After 10 seconds of execution the list should contain 10,000 bits. How can I achieve this functionality?

In this question, list is taken as an example, in my code I am using a python library, `bitarray`, which is almost like a list but holding binary data.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this without sleeping, because you need to add data in a particular rate. We need to force the system to wait to achieve to the rate.

```
from random import *
import time

data = []
rate = 10
wait_time = 1/rate
while True:
    data.append((randint(0,1)))
    time.sleep(wait_time)
```

Comment: I want to append 0s and 1s to the list based on a certain rate, for example 10 bits per second, i don't want my program to sleep for any amount of time. It should append those bits continuously. If program runs for 10 seconds, the list would contain 100 bits if the rate is 10 bits per second, that is, 100 zeros and ones. I hope you get my point.

Comment: You mean binary digits.

Comment: One doubt. Suppose your rate is 10 digits per second. What if you stop your code at 1.5 seconds?

Comment: I modified the code. I hope it satisfies your requirement. I don't think you can do this without sleep.

Comment: You said your program should run continuously without sleep, but python can add thousands of data in fraction of seconds, you need to limit the addition of data somehow.

Comment: If program runs for 1.5 second, it should add 15 bits to the list. I know Python would add thousands of bits in fraction of second, that's what I was trying to limit without any success. I though it would be possible without sleep, but your code seems to work. Thank you for the help.